# I'm losing all elements of an array. What to do?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know why, in the following code, the elements of `coupleFound` array are deleted when the function `set Interval` dies. The idea is, get into the `a` element and check her tag name `ai`.

When he accept this tag he makes a copy of the entire element starting from his parent, and put into the `coupleFound` array. It works, but only inside of `set Interval` function! I don't understand because i declared the array outside of the function!

```
var clicked = 0,
    totalClicks = 3,
    index = 0,
    listIds = new Array("289657", "2680235", "1597254", "269621"),
    coupleFound = new Array( ),
    videos = document.getElementById( "videos_list" );

var interval = setInterval(function( ) {
    coupleList = videos.getElementsByTagName( "a" );

    for(var i = coupleList.length; i--;) {
        for(j=0; j < listIds.length; j++) {
            if(coupleList[i].getAttribute( "ai" ) == listIds[j]) {
                coupleFound[index] = coupleList[i].parentNode;
                index++;
                break;
            }
        }
    videos.removeChild( videos.lastChild );
}

document.getElementById('btnMoreVideos').click();
clicked++;
if(clicked >= totalClicks) {
    clearInterval( interval );
    alert("I'm inside of the function. The length is:" + coupleFound.length)
}
}, 1000);

alert("The length of the array is:" + coupleFound.length);
```

Another weird behaviour is, when I execute this code he shows me first the alert `The length of the array is` and after that `I'm inside of the function. The length is:`
Why he is doing this?

Comment: Are you aware that `setInterval()` is a "non-blocking" function? That is, when you call it the rest of the current JS function will execute _before_ the function you pass to `setInterval()`. The alert from the last line of your code is thus executed before the function you pass to `setInterval()` is called. This also explains why the `coupleFound.length` reports as 0 in that alert: it's not that elements are deleted, it's that they haven't been added yet.

Comment: Might help if you add in some of the relevant HTML or provide a JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you did not tell me how can i solve my problem!